Retrieve User information from alternate Active Directory
My organization recently started the move over to a new domain/Active Directory. All of our servers are still on the old domain, while all the users are on the new domain. The old domain is now no longer receiving updates and is out of sync with the new domain. We currently can't manage the move of the server to the new domain.
Some of the web applications on the server queried the old domain, using the names/ID's of the users coming from the new domain. This worked while the old domain was still being synced with the new domain but is no longer working as new users no longer have records on the old domain.
This is the code that was used to find the users
public UserPrincipal FindUserDetails(string userID)
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userID);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return user;
}

Is there any way to configure IIS or alter this code to set the default domain? Preferably without encoding credentials in the source or referencing secrets.
I've tried constructing the principal context with a specific domain controller and username and password in the constructor. That worked in querying the new domain but I am looking to avoid modifying the source.

Did you look at the documentation for the types you're using? Specifically PrincipalContext?

@mason I have, I tried alternate constructors specifying the name but get access errors unless a username and password are specified. Was hoping to avoid including those

I'm not really an expert on this, but if you're trying to use an AD domain that you're not part of, I would assume you have to authenticate to it somehow, so it seems very reasonable to provide a username/password.

Depending on the authentication method used by your web applications, you may be able to configure IIS to authenticate users against the new domain while the servers remain on the old domain.
